# Java Basic: Insert data in separate Class

Tags: java

How to insert data in separate class?

```
package teste01classes;

public class Teste01Classes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Alunos[] aluno = new Alunos[20];
        aluno[0] = new Alunos();
        aluno[0].nome = "Abel";
        aluno[0].n1 = 10;
        aluno[0].n2 = 7;
        aluno[0].n3 = 8;

        aluno[1] = new Alunos();
        aluno[1].nome = "Ana Carolina";
        aluno[1].n1 = 8;
        aluno[1].n2 = 7;
        aluno[1].n3 = 5;
        //... n alunos
    }
}


package teste01classes;

public class Alunos {
    String nome;
    int n1, n2, n3;
}
```

But i need

```
    Alunos[] aluno = new Alunos[20];
    aluno[0] = new Alunos();
    aluno[0].nome = "Abel";
    aluno[0].n1 = 10;
    aluno[0].n2 = 7;
    aluno[0].n3 = 8;

    aluno[1] = new Alunos();
    aluno[1].nome = "Ana Carolina";
    aluno[1].n1 = 8;
    aluno[1].n2 = 7;
    aluno[1].n3 = 5;
    //... n alunos
```

In separated class and invoke in main.

Comment: What do you mean by in separated class? You want to create the collection of `Alunos` in a separate class, and then main just calls that method?

Comment: yes, because my data is big list... 50 alunos.

Comment: Ok, not exactly sure if it's what you want, but check my answer and let me know if it helps. Also, consider taking a look at the Java Tutorials, from Oracle (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). There are many things that can be improved in your code. For example, instead of using public instance variables, use getters and setters, and a Constructor that receives all four arguments.

Comment: was using `Alunos al[0]=new Alunos(nome,n1,n2,n3);` through constructor, more painful???

Comment: the problem you are asking is so basic if you know a little of java and object oriented. you should be able to find the tutorial online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new class, say `SchoolClass`, with a `createAlunos` method that will create all `alunos`:

```
package teste01classes;    

public class SchoolClass {

  public static Alunos[] createAlunos() {
    Alunos[] aluno = new Alunos[20];
    aluno[0] = new Alunos();
    aluno[0].nome = "Abel";
    aluno[0].n1 = 10;
    aluno[0].n2 = 7;
    aluno[0].n3 = 8;
    //... n alunos
    return aluno;
  }
}
```

And then, in `Teste01Classes`, call this method:

```
public class Teste01Classes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Alunos[] aluno = SchoolClass.createAlunos();
    }
}
```